# Интерпретация php на сайтах stackoverflow.com

Tags: предложение, сниппеты

Сорри если я не первый кто подымает такую тему, и заранее если я не туда пишу.

Почему на stackoverflow нет опции интерпретации простых скриптов, для демонстрации работоспособности алгоритма? Часто приходиться давать ссылки на другие ресурсы «онлайн интерпретаторы» для демонстрации. А хотелось бы, чтобы такая функция существовала и для ответов в которых есть PHP сниппет кода.

Comment: Всё ок, вы по адресу, и, скорее всего, вы первый, кто осмелился задать такой вопрос здесь. И, скорее всего, это не реализуют, т. к. технически сложно, дорого и рискованно поддерживать, а толку почти ноль. HTML/CSS/JS-сниппеты ж выполняют сами браузеры и не создают дополнительной нагрузки. Но даже они вызвали свою долю критики в стиле "вот зачем вы поощряете телеги кода?"

Comment: @D-side ну я не говорю прям про телегу кода, можно же просто ограничить код входными данными, 10-15 строк кода, кэшируем выполнение кода единежды, и предоставляем этот вывод, если же отредактировали, вычисляем и обновляем кэш вывода.

Comment: Поддерживать несколько версий хлопотно, многие функции языка придётся отключить по соображениям безопасности (взлом сервера, потенциальный ДДоС других сайтов и т.п.), взлом самого сервера или вывод из строя декартовыми перемножениями и бесконечными циклами  (PHP - серверный язык, это вам не javascript выполнять на браузере пользователя). Однократное выполнение (при создании) - это плохой путь: можете тогда сами свой код взять и один раз запустить. В общем -- игра не стоит свеч. И чем PHP в этом плане лучше других языков? Я может быть хотел бы C# тогда, а кто-то Java попросит. Где предел?

Comment: Что с минусами набросились-то? Вроде, на МСЕ писали, что над возможностью добавления языков помимо жабоскрипта они думают. Проблема в том, что это дорого.

Answer (score 10):

## Против.

#### Слишком технически сложно, а толку от этого мало.

- Поскольку это серверный язык, это потребует дополнительных вычислительных мощностей со стороны SE. А это стоит денег, которые можно употребить на более интересные и полезные нужды.
- Поскольку это серверный язык (2), нужно либо постоянно держать эндпойнт для запросов к сниппету, либо дополнять сниппет совершаемым запросом... но раз уж на то пошло, можно при написании ответа самостоятельно этот запрос совершить и приложить результат.
- Что делать с разными версиями PHP? С разными конфигурациями? Результаты ведь будут отличаться в зависимости от них.
- Что делать с опасными фичами вроде доступа наружу и использования сторонних библиотек? Если это поотключать, останется не так уж много практических вопросов, в которые можно приложить осмысленный сниппет.
- Это будет поощрять вложение больших телег кода в вопросы и ответы под предлогом "воспроизводится, что ещё удалить не знаю!" Даже HTML/CSS/JS-сниппеты критиковали за то, что они оказывают подобный эффект на собщество.

  - Ограничение на строчки не прокатит. Будут ужимать в длинные строки с короткими идентификаторами, получая в результате *устрашающий код*. Можно дополнительно публиковать "нормальную" версию кода, тогда дополнительно возникает проблема "рассинхрона" между двумя версиями: когда поведение написанной и сжатой версий отличается.

Comment: ideone‎‏‎‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏

Comment: @Qwertiy это инструмент сам по себе. Здесь мы его рассматриваем в контексте Q&A. И вопросы у нас обычно не про сферические скриптики в вакууме, которые работают на ideone.

Comment: @D-side Вы не поверите, но на СО куча ссылок на ideone. Есть множество вопросов по языкам и стандартной библиотеке, поэтому польза очевидна. Да, не так круто, как в JS, где можно без проблем подключать множество библиотек, но ведь и для JS нет возможности запускать всякие Node.js.

Comment: @Squidward много? Да. Большой ли процент? Настолько ли большой, чтобы имело смысл делать штатный аналог ideone? Или, скажем, договориться с ideone об энтерпрайз-тарифе на их Sphere Engine, как это сделано с imgur?

Comment: @D-side Так или иначе, проблема решаемая, вопрос в деньгах.

Comment: @Squidward не только в деньгах. Мой тезис: можно раскошелиться, если польза для большого количества вопросов здесь велика. Я считаю, что подходящих вопросов здесь мало.

Comment: @D-side но они всё таки есть

Answer (score 3):

Я интересовался подобным вопросом в рамках примеров для Документации. Как мне кажется, ответ будет аналогичен и примерим к фрагментам кода в вопросах и ответах.

#### Подобный функционал добавит больше вреда, чем пользы.

(В дополнение ответа [D-side](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3499/6).) К примеру, чтобы выполнить простой фрагмент С–кода, необходимо иметь не только код указанный участником, но и функцию main, вызывающую функцию, выставленные глобальные переменные, правильные опции компилятора и еще уйма всего (данные ограничения будут справедливы практически для всех языков программирования). С большой вероятностью, результирующая система будет слишком сложна как в реализации, так и в использовании.

Comment: а если использовать какой-нибудь интерпретатор целевого языка на яваскрипте?

Comment: @Grundy Подскажите, как это поможет в случае, когда автор вопроса указал лишь одну функцию на псевдо-С++ которая не компилируется?

Comment: В этом случае никак :-) а вот если он выбрал конкретную версию c++ и предоставленного списка, то вполне. Никто ж не говорит про поддержку всех версий всех возможных языков и их компиляторов :)

Comment: @Grundy Опять же, нужна вызывающая функци, нужна `main`. А что если это не консольное приложение, а требует графической системы, например, Win32? 1) Там уйма разных входных точек, 2) обработка происходит в WndProc, то есть нам надо предоставленный код вставить в какую–то шаблонную функцию в какое–то место. И так далее... И для каждого языка таких вопросов миллионы!

Comment: Волевым решением ограничить примеры только консольными приложениями, причем функция `main`, может быть как жестко забита со стороны сниппета, так и обязательно присутствовать в коде пользователя. Тут вообще можно сделать как можно больше ограничений, чтобы не было возможности добавить _нерабочий_ сниппет :)

Comment: @Grundy Собрав статистику, может оказаться, что в большинстве случаев, подобный подход будет просто не используемым, то есть не нужным. (Что–то мне подсказывает, что так оно и есть.)

Comment: ха-ха, теги не работают в комментариях, баг или фича? :-D В большинстве простых случаев как раз такого подхода и хватит :)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky ну почему нельзя двоим отправить ответ, или просто не подсвечивает... Вопрос был про php и к стати идея интерпритация php js неплохая...

Comment: @Naumov Пожалуйста, поясните ваш вопрос в комментарии. Привожу  C++ примеры так как не владею достаточными знаниями по php, чтобы рассуждать о нем, но считаю результирующие проблемы одинаковыми для практически всех языков.

Comment: @Naumov, в данном случае, уведомление автору ответа приходит всегда, при любом комментарии под ответом, поэтому его можно не указывать напрямую

Comment: Тут просто надо разделить интерпритируемые языки(точнее скриптовые) и языки компилируемые. В C,C++ точкой входа будет являться функция main(не знаю можно ли её переопределить), в интерпретируемом скриптовом языке таких как php и js, точко входа начало файла. Так что думаю вполне возможно написать библиотеку которая будет разбирать php(тут нужно сделать допущение нативный без расширений) код на js и выдовать результат в общем можно говорить об эмуляции интерпетатора. и да я немного удивлён но такой интерпретатор уже есть https://github.com/asmblah/uniter

Comment: Кроме языков с укуренным количеством декораций (C++, Java и прочих) есть множество интпретируемых языков, в которых "hello world" представляет собой ровно одну строчку, как и в JS. Даже для C# есть официальный скриптовый диалект.